# How to pass data class as parameter in kotlin extension

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

i have a data class like:

```
data class GetDoctorResponse(
    val BrickName: String,
    val Class: String,
    val DoctorAddress
)
```

Now i want to get response, so i get it like this:

```
val myResponse = Gson().fromJson("response in json", Array<GetDoctorResponse>::class.java).toList()
```

my question is how can i create an extension which takes data and class and return me response like above.

i have tried this:

```
fun getResponse(data: String, it: Class<T>) : List<it> =
    Gson().fromJson(data, Array<it>::class.java).toList()
```

but T is unresolved here, and i want to get response of any data class i passed.

```
val response = getResponse(data, SomeClass())
```

Comment: `fun <T> getResponse(data: String, it: Class<T>) : List<T> =
    Gson().fromJson(data, Array<it>::class.java).toList()`

Comment: Updating my answer

Comment: @sidgate Array<it>, here <it> is unresolved

Answer (score 3):

> You need to Pass  type also.
>    I didn't test it so let me know it worked or not.

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> getResponse(data: String) : List<T> =
        Gson().fromJson(data, Array<T>::class.java).toList()
```

Comment: sorry kotlin is not too old for me, how to call this function?

val response = getResponse(data, SomeClass())

Comment: getResponse<class>(data); and please let me know if it's not worked. I need to test after that and update answer

Comment: val myResponse = getResponse<GetDoctorResponse::class.java>(data) is not working

Comment: @MaK pass <GetDoctorResponse>

Comment: val myResponse = getResponse<GetDoctorResponse>(data)

Comment: Converting Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to package.name.data.models.retrofit.GetDoctorResponse

Comment: @MaK let me reprouce the issue, show the example json in your question

Comment: @AnimeshSahu [
   {
      "DoctorNo":"34692",
      "DoctorName":"Aziz Kaniyo",
      "DoctorAddress":"12 Mill",
      "Class":"A",
      "SpecialityAbbr":"GP",
      "BrickName":"12 Mile"
   },
   {
      "DoctorNo":"34691",
      "DoctorName":"Ghansham Das Khatri",
      "DoctorAddress":"12 mil",
      "Class":"A+",
      "SpecialityAbbr":"GP",
      "BrickName":"12 Mile"
   }]

Comment: @MaK This actually works for me, i don't have any issues, could you reporoduce the error via running the following gist https://gist.github.com/Animeshz/d53edc8a8b24868850c33ee4606417b9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211606/discussion-between-mak-and-animesh-sahu).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks every one who helped me.

what i did is create this extension

```
fun <T> getResponse(data: String, model: Class<Array<T>>): List<T> =
    Gson().fromJson(data, model).toList()
```

and call it as

```
val myResponse = getResponse(data, Array<GetDoctorResponse>::class.java)
```

and its working.